# Create a pst file with a bunch of msg files using win32com python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, msg, pst

I have a bunch of `msg` files in a directory, I'd like to kinda put/zip them in a `pst` file. I've seen some solutions like `Aspos Email` which needs JVM on the machine. I want to do it with Outlook itself using `win32com.client`. Please post if there is a way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Why not just drag them from a Windows Explorer window into an Outlook folder? There's no need to program anything to do this.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod well, that's a good suggestion, but this script will be a small part of a big automation tool.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook Object Model, call `Namespace.AddStore` (or `AddStoreEx`) to add a new PST file, find the store in the `Namespace.Stores` collection (`AddStore` does not return the newly added store), call `Store.GetRootFolder()` to get the top level folder and add folders and items. Keep in mind that OOM code cannot run in a service, and that you need to log to an existing profile in Outlook first (`Namespace.Logon`).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option (it can run in a service and does not require to log to an existing profile first), but can create a PST file as well as create folders and messages there. In VB script:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
set pstStore = Session.LogonPstStore("c:\temp\test.pst", 1, "Test PST Store" )
set RootFolder = pstStore.IPMRootFolder
set newFolder = RootFolder.Folders.OpenOrAdd("Test folder")
set newItem = newFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Note")

newItem.Sent = true
newItem.Subject = "test"
newItem.HTMLBody = "test <b>bold</b> text"
newItem.Recipients.AddEx "The user", "user@domain.demo", "SMTP", olTo
vSenderEntryId = Session.AddressBook.CreateOneOffEntryID("Joe The Sender", "SMTP", "joe@domain.demo", false, true)
set vSender = Session.AddressBook.GetAddressEntryFromID(vSenderEntryId)
newItem.Sender = vSender
newItem.SentOnBehalfOf = vSender
newItem.SentOn = Now
newItem.ReceivedTime = Now
newItem.Save
```